# Cordova with Angular - Debug with Typescript Files?

Tags: typescript, cordova

I am trying to debug the application with the source files. They are Typescript files. I am debugging with chrome but I can only debug javascript files generated by cordova and it is hard to debug it. Is it possible to debug the typescript files?

```
ng b --project=<NameProject>
cordova build android
cordova run android
```

Comment: You can generate source maps. More information regarding your setup would be required.

Answer (score 1):

No. Since you generate code with a framework, you are stuck with the generated code.